# Get name corresponding to max value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I am having a problem with Google-Sheets, basically what I am having is a sheet where me and my mates write down our weight progress day by day. I want to get the name corresponding to max value , but  I am getting an error.

[image]

The function that U've used is  this:

```
=INDEX(B3:G3,MATCH(MAX(B2:G2),B2:G2,0))
```

Getting back and error, why is that?
Something that has to do with the indexes not being in columns but in rows?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, please share a sample sheet.

Comment: What is your locale ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Google sheets Max]

May be you need something like this

Comment: how come I do the same and and I am getting back an #NAME?  thing

Comment: edit : i am getting ERROR

Comment: for #NAME error you might miss out something try this =Transpose(FILTER(B3:G4,B3:G3=max(B3:G3)))

Comment: yes I did it,   I even transponed manually and used my function mentioned above, and still all I am getting is an #ERROR!  , I guess its something else ,because the implementation should be fine .

Comment: can you share your sheets?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B2:G3; B2:G2=MAX(B2:G2)))
```

or:

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:G3); "select max(Col1),Col2")
```